# Can't log into the XP Mode in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

My PC config:

Host OS - Windows 7 32-bit
Guest OS - Windows XP SP3

When I enable the integration features (in the settings dialog), check the "enable at start up" option, on start up I'm asked the password with which I'll be logged in.  When I enter the password a message appears:

> "The system could not log you on.Make
>   sure your user name and domain are
>   correct, than type your password
>   again..."

**BUT**: when I disable the integration features, I can log on successfully(no password is asked).

Answer (score 2):

Is it not possible to set the password after you log on with Integration features disabled? Then it should be no problem restarting with integration on and enter the new password!

Personally, it seems I must give the password even when integration is turned of and I have forgotten it :(